# Add missing properties to an object with a blank value if they don't exist

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with different properties:

```
var arr = [];

var obj_1 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a',
    'key_b': 'value_b'
};

arr.push(obj_1);

var obj_2 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a',
    'key_b': 'value_b',
    'key_c': 'value_c'
};

arr.push(obj_2);
```

How do I automatically add the new key (key_c), or any other key, to every object in the array with a blank value if it doesn't already exist?

So the array would look like this:

```
    [
        {
            'key_a': 'value_a'
            'key_b': 'value_b'
            'key_c': ''
        },
        {
            'key_a': 'value_a'
            'key_b': 'value_b'
            'key_c': 'value_c'
        }
    ]
```

**Please note:** I'm building a web scraper and unknown keys/properties will be added to objects and pushed to the array in a foreach loop.

Comment: Why would you like to bloat your array while keeping the object as it is may keep the size optimal. I suggest that in your for loop you can build another array which holds the super list of properties so that they may be useful when are reading objects from the original array.

Comment: Do you know beforehand which keys you expect?

Comment: @Bergi I will not know the keys before hand :(

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, however I will not know the keys beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a special object to act as a container. This special object would storage the keys of the objects pushed into it as well as the objects.

Once the user wants to retrieve the objects from it, this object would update the keys of the stored objects to make sure all of them have the same keys with the correct values.

```
var SpecialArray = function () {
    var keys = Object.create(null),
        objs = [];

    this.push = function (obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys[key] = true;
            }
        };

        objs.push(obj);
        return this;
    };

    this.toArray = function () {
        objs.forEach(function (current) {
            for (var key in keys) {
                if (current[key] === undefined) {
                    current[key] = '';
                }
            }
        });
        return objs;
    };
};

var obj1 = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'hello'
};

var obj2 = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'hello',
    c: 'hola'
};

var f = new SpecialArray;
console.log(f.push(obj1).push(obj2).toArray());
```

You can add functionality to this object to improve it.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9uoabp8/1/)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I automatically add the new key (key_c), or any other key, to every object in the array with a blank value if it doesn't already exist?

You'd have to spin through the array, checking each of the objects for keys that they don't yet have, and adding them, which would be a pain.

**Instead**, you could have a prototype object with all of the properties with default values, and use that prototype behind all of your concrete objects. As you learn of new keys, add them to the prototype with default values, and they'll seem to magically appear on all the previous objects retroactively (because you're modifying the prototype behind them). Later when getting the properties from the objects, they'll use their own values for the properties they have, and default values from the prototype for the ones they don't.

To create an object using another object as its prototype, you use `Object.create`:

```
obj = Object.create(defaults); // defaults is the prototype object to use
```

If you're receiving the objects you need to track from somewhere else (e.g., you're not creating them), you can use a function to create an object using the "defaults" and then copy over any properties the object you received has. That's also an opportunity to flag up any new properties you don't already know about and set defaults for them:

```
var defaults = {};
var list = [];

function addToList(obj) {
    // Create our entry backed by the defaults
    var entry = Object.create(defaults);

    // Loop through the new object's keys...
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        // ...adding a default if it's a new key
        if (!defaults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            defaults[key] = /*...default value...*/;
        }
        // ...and grabbing the value
        entry[key] = obj[key];
    });

    // Put it on the list
    list.push(entry);
}
```

**Live example:**

```js
var defaults = {};
var list = [];

function addToList(obj) {
  // Create our entry backed by the defaults
  var entry = Object.create(defaults);
  
  // Loop through the new object's keys...
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    // ...adding a default if it's a new key
    if (!defaults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      defaults[key] = "default for " + key;
    }
    // ...and grabbing the value
    entry[key] = obj[key];
  });
  
  // Put it on the list
  list.push(entry);
}

addToList({a: "a0", b: "b0"}); // Has a and b
addToList({a: "a1", c: "c1"}); // Has a and c
addToList({b: "b2", d: "d2"}); // Has b and d

list.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  snippet.log("Object #" + index + ":");
  Object.keys(defaults).forEach(function(key) {
    snippet.log(key + " = " + entry[key]);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A roundabout way to implement property missing by via extend function like so:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';    

    var commonPrototype = new function() {
        var self = this;
        self.getProp = function(key) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                return this[key];
            }
            
            return 'DEFAULT';  //change to empty string if you want
        }
    };
    
    var a = [];
    
    var lit = {
        'key1' : 'key1Value',
        'key2' : 'key2Value'
    };
    
    extend(lit, commonPrototype);    
    a.push(lit);
    
    var lit2 = {
        'key1' : 'key1Value',
        'key2' : 'key2Value',
        'key3' : 'key3Value'
    };    
    extend(lit2, commonPrototype);
    a.push(lit2);
    
    console.log(a[1].getProp('key3'));     //return actual lit2 key3 value
  
    console.log(a[0].getProp('key3'));    //return the default (DEFAULT or whatever you want) when it's missing
    
    function extend(o, p) {
        o.getProp = p.getProp;        
    }
        
}());
```

Only problem here is the default accessor will not work correctly, but you can use the `getProp(keyName)` to get the value.

This can be so much nicer when ES6 comes around using `Proxy` like so:

```
function proxify(o) {
    return new Proxy(o, {
        get : function(target, name, receiver) {
                  return (target.hasOwnProperty(name)) ? target[name] : "DEFAULT";
        }
    });
}

var l1 = proxify({ key1: '1', key2: '2'});
var l2 = proxify({ key1: '1.1', key2: '1.2', key3: '1.3'});

console.log(`l1.key3: ${l1.key3}`);
console.log(`l2.key3: ${l2.key3}`);
```

I wish you can just replace how prop accessor with your own code but this will do.

That code is executable on Firefox 37+ and Microsoft Edge (formerly Spartan) as of 2015-04-26.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that i completely understand your question, but if you want to add blank keys to objects if they don't have it you can do this:

```
var obj_1 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a',
    'key_b': 'value_b'
};
if(!obj_1.hasOwnProperty("key_c"))
    obj_1.key_c=undfined;
```

The idea is that you are checking object property existence instead of undefined value.

Other option is to call `Object.keys(obj_1)//["key_a","key_b"]`
and check if the wanted key is in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
var keysSet = new Set();
var pushWithFill = function(arr, newObject) {
    // add keys from the new obj to the dictionary
    // and add missing properties to this object
    keysSet.forEach(function(key){
        if (!newObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newObject[key] = '';
        }
    });
    for (var property in newObject) {
        keysSet.add(property);
    }

    // process all stored objects to add keys from the new one to them
    arr.forEach(function(storedObj, index){
        for (var property in newObject) {
             if (!storedObj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    storedObj[property] = '';
             } 
        }
    });

    arr.push(newObject);
};
```

Example usage:

```
var arr = [];

var obj_1 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a',
    'key_b': 'value_b'
};
var obj_2 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a',
    'key_b': 'value_b',
    'key_c': 'value_c'
};
var obj_3 = {
    'key_a': 'value_a'
}

pushWithFill(arr, obj_1);
pushWithFill(arr, obj_2);
pushWithFill(arr, obj_3);
```

The result:

```
[{
        " key_a " : " value_a ",
        " key_b " : " value_b ",
        " key_c " : " "
    }, {
        " key_a " : " value_a ",
        " key_b " : " value_b ",
        " key_c " : " value_c "
    }, {
        " key_a " : " value_a ",
        " key_b " : " ",
        " key_c " : " "
    }
]
```